Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'"
I have tried to deploy my full stack mern up on vercel, and uploaded both the backend and frontend separately, however it is not working and i get this error on my console.
(https://i.sstatic.net/CNFmy.png)
Then in my frontend when i make a form submission to login i get this error, notice how it has undefined in the URL, i went through my whole code and i do not know where it may have gone wrong, i am using a .env to store the backend port and using the .env variable for the port e.g
${backendUrl}/auth/login
(https://i.sstatic.net/c1ejv.png)

I have just removed the font and i still get the same error but i cannot tell where from, i never got this error in development

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
